# Seaborn distplot remove empty plots

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 4 columns. I want to plot it in sns.distplot as following:

`g = sns.displot(dataframe, height = 25, kind = "kde", x = "value", fill = True, hue = "Testset", col = "Session", row = "Timepoint")`

It produces the following plot with empty subplots, because I don't have all the combinations of values. Is there a way to remove the empty plots and plot it under one another.
[image]